Add timezone based on Column Value
I have a polars Dataframe with two columns: a string column containing datetimes and an integer column containing UTC offsets (for example -4 for EDT). Essentially the Dataframe looks like this:
>>> data
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ Datetime            ┆ Timezone │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      │
│ str                 ┆ i64      │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 12:52:23 ┆ -4       │
│ 2023-03-31 04:22:59 ┆ -5       │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┘

Now I want to convert this column either to UTC or a timezone-aware datetime column. I looked into the pl.Expr.str.to_datetime function which accepts the time_zone argument. Unfortunately this argument can only be passed as a string and not as a pl.Expr.
In other words, I can convert all columns to the same specified timezone, but I cannot dynamically use timezone based on the value of another column.
What I would like in the end is something like the following (note that the Datetime column is now of datetime type and the timezone offset has been added dynamically (4 hours for the first row and 5 for the second).
>>> data
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ Datetime            ┆ Timezone │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      │
│ datetime            ┆ i64      │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 16:52:23 ┆ -4       │
│ 2023-03-31 09:22:59 ┆ -5       │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┘

Is there a way to do this without going to map_elements or iter_rows based approaches?

Can you use .dt.offset_by() instead?

Alternatively, do you have an example of an exact string you would pass as time_zone for a single call? e.g. pl.lit('2022-01-01 16:52:23').str.to_datetime(time_zone=...)

@jqurious Thinking about it a bit more, perhaps it was not quite accurate to describe the 2nd column as "Timezone" as its more of a UTC offset. I think ultimately I want to convert it into some kind of timezone aware time column, I'm indifferent to whether it's in UTC or America/New York or anything else.

If you're ok with keeping things in UTC, you can use
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"Datetime": ["2022-01-01 12:52:23", "2023-03-31 04:22:59"], "Timezone": [-4, -5]}
)

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("Datetime")
    .str.to_datetime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time_zone="UTC")
    .dt.offset_by(pl.format("{}h", -pl.col("Timezone")))
    .alias("dt_conv")
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ Datetime            ┆ Timezone ┆ dt_conv                 │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---                     │
│ str                 ┆ i64      ┆ datetime[μs, UTC]       │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 12:52:23 ┆ -4       ┆ 2022-01-01 16:52:23 UTC │
│ 2023-03-31 04:22:59 ┆ -5       ┆ 2023-03-31 09:22:59 UTC │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────────┘


This looks great. I guess the only downside is the two-step procedure and need to keep it all in specific timezones. On that note are multiple timezones within the same column even supported?

From the documentation.

Note that, because a Datetime can only have a single time zone, it is
impossible to have a column with multiple time zones. If you are
parsing data with multiple offsets, you may want to pass utc=True to
convert them all to a common time zone (UTC), see parsing dates and times.

Hence, a solution (like the one above) fully relying on UTC seems most appropriate.
